# I think vs I believe vs I suppose

Tags: word-usage

When expressing my point of view, which is better to use, or are there any differences between "I think", "I believe" and "I suppose"?

For example, if we are comparing two methods A and B.

- I think method B is better because...
- I believe method B is better because...
- I suppose method B is better because...

Will "think" sounds more aggressive and "suppose" more polite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Think” and “believe” are generally used interchangeably, though there are some very subtle differences in connotation. For instance, in a classroom setting, it may be more suitable to say “I think the answer is…” rather than “I believe the answer is…”, as the word “believe” indicates a stronger conviction and stance. The phrase “I suppose” is used much less often, as it implies an “I guess so” kind of attitude that’s not very firm.

In terms of strength of expression, I would rank it as “believe” > “think” > “suppose.”

“I suppose” might be considered to come across as more polite simply because of the fact that it is less “strong-willed.” However, I seldom use the phrase to express myself, as I personally feel that it doesn’t convey my thoughts very concretely.

I consider “I think” to be the most generally applicable for daily use, as it tends to be suitable for a wide range of situations.

Comment: That's very useful! Very much thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am a speaker of American English and have a slightly different opinion.

"I think" and "I believe" tend to be used interchangeably in informal situations; however, in business contexts I have had managers who object to using "I believe."  I think the subtle distinction, if you are forced to make one, is that "I think" reflects you reasoning and logic; whereas "I believe" reflects your opinion, your intuition, and your feelings.  Again, in casual conversation, I don't think (!) anybody makes a big difference between the expressions.

"I suppose," on the other hand, expressly conveys that you have not given thorough consideration to what you are about to say and so are still uncertain of its value.  In an appropriate circumstance, this can suggest that you don't want to be forceful in a suggestion (e.g., "I suppose we could eat out if you really don't want to cook"), but it can also suggest being unacceptably lazy with your thinking if you are expected to have a well thought out view about something (i.e., "I suppose our sales will be on target this month").  Your bosse's answer to the latter might well be: "You mean you don't actually know yet?  What do you mean 'you suppose.'"